Tailwind flex item adjust to max width
Got this flex component on Tailwind and want to ensure the item inside always use the full with even if the content is not enough widht, basically cover all the red box area.

<section class="mx-auto grid max-w-[1200px] grid-cols-1 px-5 pb-10">
    <div class="flex justify-between w-full gap-x-6 py-5">
        <div class="flex min-w-0 gap-x-4 flex-grow">
            <img class="h-24 w-24 flex-none rounded-md bg-gray-50"
                 src="./assets/images/product-chair.png"
                 alt="">
            <div class="min-w-0 flex-auto">
                <p class="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">Leslie Alexander</p>
                <p class="mt-1 truncate text-xs leading-5 text-gray-500">leslie.alexander@example.com</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden shrink-0 sm:flex sm:flex-col sm:items-end">
            <p class="text-sm leading-6 text-gray-900">Co-Founder / CEO</p>
            <p class="mt-1 text-xs leading-5 text-gray-500">Last seen
                <time datetime="2023-01-23T13:23Z">3h ago</time>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

If for example the text of the email is long enough it extend the item width but want to have it always.


<section class="mx-auto grid max-w-[1200px] grid-cols-1 px-5 pb-10">
<div class="flex justify-between w-full gap-x-6 py-5">
    <div class="flex min-w-0 gap-x-4 flex-grow">
        <img class="h-24 w-24 flex-none rounded-md bg-gray-50"
             src="./assets/images/product-chair.png"
             alt="">
        <div class="min-w-0 flex-auto">
            <p class="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">Leslie Alexander</p>
            <p class="mt-1 truncate text-xs leading-5 text-gray-500">leslie.alexander@example.com</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-col items-end">
        <p class="text-sm leading-6 text-gray-900">Co-Founder / CEO</p>
        <p class="mt-1 text-xs leading-5 text-gray-500">Last seen
            <time datetime="2023-01-23T13:23Z">3h ago</time>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>


Thanks for the answer @khusbu-patel but that didn't work :/

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Ensure that the flex item inside the red box always covers the full width of its container, even if the content is not enough to fill the available width,  you can adjust the CSS. Instead of using max-width, you can try with width or min-width. You can find the updated code in the below snippet.
<section class="mx-auto grid w-[1200px] grid-cols-1 px-5 pb-10">
    <div class="flex w-full justify-between gap-x-6 py-5">
      <div class="flex min-w-0 flex-grow gap-x-4">
        <img class="h-24 w-24 flex-none rounded-md bg-gray-50" src="./assets/images/product-chair.png" alt="" />
        <div class="min-w-0 flex-auto">
          <p class="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">Leslie Alexander</p>
          <p class="mt-1 truncate text-xs leading-5 text-gray-500">leslie.alexander@example.com</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden shrink-0 sm:flex sm:flex-col sm:items-end">
        <p class="text-sm leading-6 text-gray-900">Co-Founder / CEO</p>
         <p class="mt-1 text-xs leading-5 text-gray-500">
           Last seen
           <time datetime="2023-01-23T13:23Z">3h ago</time>
         </p>
       </div>
    </div>
</section>


Thanks for your response, I paste the code and didn't work. Im new on all this CSS stuff and I think max-w-[1200px] is there more as a big screen limit.
